# Is it possible to use mimic selection to move a planning entity linked to the originally selected planning entity?

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

I'm currently working on solving a VRP with pickups, dropoffs and time windows with Optaplanner.

A load to be delivered is comprised of two `LoadJobs`:

```
@DeepPlanningClone
class Load {
    lateinit var pickup: LoadJob
        private set
    lateinit var dropoff: LoadJob
        private set
}
```

A `LoadJob` is a `PlanningEntity` and has a `timeWindow` within it can be fulfilled as well as a `Location` where it has to be fulfilled:

```
@PlanningEntity
class LoadJob {
    lateinit var load: Load
        private set
    lateinit var timeWindow: Interval
        private set
    lateinit var location: Location
        private set
}
```

Additionally to the time constraints on the load jobs themselves, a `Location` itself has `openingTimes`, during which the `LoadJobs` may be fulfilled.

The `LoadJobs` are put on `Vehicles` to form tours. Each pickup has to occur before its respective dropoff.

```
@PlanningEntity
class Vehicle {
    @PlanningListVariable lateinit var tour: MutableList<LoadJob>
}
```

When changing one pickup `LoadJob` to another Vehicle, it does not make sense to not move its corresponding dropoff to the same vehicle. Currently, I've implemented a custom `MoveIteratorFactory` similar to the one in [Geoffrey's VRP experiment from a few years back](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/optaplanner-mixedvrp-experiment/blob/master/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/vehiclerouting/solver/move/RideChangeMoveIteratorFactory.java) to create `CompositeMove`s which follow this constraint.

Could this also be achieved using mimic selection? Like e.g. configuring something like

```
<entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="entitySelector"/>
<valueSelector variableName="load.dropoff"/>
```

If not, are custom `MoveIteratorFactory` implementations the way to go here?

If so, what are the dangers in the approach taken in the VRP-Experiment mentioned before and are there ways to mitigate them in newer versions of Optaplanner or Timefold?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on the problem you want to solve. Why do you need two loadJobs per location visit? Based on existing description it looks like you can create the Visit planning entity linked to specific vehicle via planning variable and assume that during visit you unload all cargo and take all available pickups (or as many pickup crago as remaining vehicle capacity allows). In this case you can avoid using two planning variables.

Comment: I've updated the question with information regarding the time window constraints on the `LoadJob` instances and on the `Location`s. I fear, with the simplfied approach you proposed we are not flexible enough to achieve good results.

Comment: The main challenge we are basically facing right now is to group return loads containing empty packaging onto the same vehicle together with full loads. Optaplanner is able to find this most of the time, however, most of the time, there remain some instances where loads with common locations are not grouped together well enough.